# Is my proof by induction of $4^k > k^2$ for $k \geq 1$ valid?

Tags: solution-verification, induction

I realize that other people have asked about $4^{(k-1)}$ but this is slightly different.

I prove the result using induction.

I start with the base case $ k = 1$ which is easily checked. Now I suppose that $4^k >k^2$  and I try to prove that $4^{k+1}>(k+1)^2$.

We have $4^{k+1} = 4 \times 4^k > 4 \times k^2 = 4k^2.$

I've managed to prove that $4k^2 > (k+1)^2$ for all $k >1$.

Notice that the original question asked to prove for $k \geq 1$ but does my proof still prove the induction?

Comment: How did you get to your conclusion? It seems to be incorrect and your question is not clear. How did you arrive at $4(k^2) > (k+1)^2$?

Comment: if 4(k^2) > (k+1)^2 then 4^(k+1) >(k+1)^2. if a>b and b>c then a>c

Comment: Thats true, but its not under the domain you want. You have proved it for $k > 1$ but then the question is asking you for $k \ge 1$. This means there is some inconsistency and the just implying $4(k^2) > (k+1)^2$ onto $4^{k+1} >(k+1)^2$ does not work.

Comment: ok what other way is there of doing this question without the method someone pointed out below

Comment: Instead try something like; We know $4^k > k^2$, then we find the similarities with $$4*(4^k) > k^2 + 2k + 1$$ $$\to \color{red}{4^k} + 3*4^k > \color{red}{k^2} + 2k + 1$$. Since we already proved $4^k > k^2$, we only need to prove $3*4^k > 2k + 1$, which is trivial.

Comment: trivial meaning it's immediately evident?

Comment: Yes, one is exponential and the other is linear with $3 * 4(1) > 2(1) + 1$. If you want rigorous methods in your proof, you can apply induction here and complete it (should be easier than the quadratic) or you can compare their gradients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your proof is almost finished. You can only use $4k^2 >(k+1)^2$ for $k \geq 2$. So start your proof by induction at the base case $k =2$. Then by your argument you have
proven that$$ 4^{k+1} = 4 \times 4^k > 4k^2 > (k+1)^2$$
for all $k \geq 2$. Now you only have to check that the equality is true for $k = 1$ (obvious) which proves that the inequality holds for all $k \geq 1.$

Comment: Brilliant, this is what I was looking for thank you! I just wondered why it shows k>1 in the final quadratic and not k>= 1 whilst the whole solution holds for k>=1

Comment: @MG I'm not sure there is a reason. At least I can't think of a meaningful one.

Comment: @Digitallis Can you look at this? Thank you. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4254992/trying-to-find-a-closed-form-for-sum-k-1nkn/4255290?noredirect=1#comment9722742_4255290

Answer (score 0):

For a simple proof: $$4^k = (2*2)^k = (2^k)^2 > k^2$$ iff $$2^k>k$$
which is true for all $k$ natural. You can apply induction on this part if you wish.

Comment: The person is asking for feedback on their proof. This does not answer the question.