How to calculate the limit as follow?
The limit is as follows
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^1+n^2+\cdots+n^n}
\end{align*}
Since $e^x\ge 1+x$ for any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, on the one hand
\begin{gather*}
    \sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\le \sum_{k=0}^n \left(e^{-\frac{k}{n}}\right)^n\le \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{e}{e-1},\\
    \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\le \frac{e}{e-1}.
\end{gather*}
On the other hand, for any $m\le n$, we have
\begin{align*}
    \sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\ge \sum_{k=0}^m\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n.
\end{align*}
Taking the limit as $n\to\infty$ on both sides of the inequality and then as $m\to\infty$, then
\begin{gather*}
    \liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\ge \sum_{k=0}^m\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\sum_{k=0}^me^{-k},\\
    \liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\ge \sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{e}{e-1}.
\end{gather*}
Therefore, we can conclude that
\begin{gather*}
    \frac{e}{e-1}\le \liminf_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\le \limsup_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n\le \frac{e}{e-1},\\
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^n\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{e-1}.
\end{gather*}
Finally, we can figure out the limit
\begin{align*}
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^1+n^2+\cdots+n^n}&=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^n}\cdot \frac{n^n}{n^1+n^2+\cdots+n^n}\\
    &=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{e-1}.
\end{align*}
Is my proof correct? I am thinking about whether it is possible to find this limit without using the squeeze theorem, or if I can directly obtain the result using the definition of definite integrals.

Can't we interchange the limit and sum by DCT?

@ Bob Dobbs. It seems sufficient to use the Levi Monotone Convergence Theorem here.

I know Levi's pants.:) Thanks @Scorpio I will read LMCT on Wikipedia if a page about it exists.

$$A_n=\sum_{k=1}^n k^n=H_n^{(-n)}=\zeta (-n)-\zeta (-n,n+1)$$ where appear Riemann zeta and Hurwitz zeta functions.
These form sequence $A031971$ in $OEIS$ and, asymptotically
$$A_n\sim\frac{n^n (e n+1)}{(e-1) (n+1)}$$ which is a very good approximation.
$$B_n=\sum_{k=1}^n n^k=\frac{n \left(n^n-1\right)}{n-1}$$ So, expanded as series for large $n$
$$\frac {A_n}{B_n}=\frac{n^n}{n^n-1}\Bigg(\frac{e}{e-1}-\frac{2 e-1}{(e-1)
   n}+\frac{2}{n(n+1)}\Bigg) $$
For $n=100$, the above truncated series gives $\color{red}{1.5563}55$
Since the front coefficient is very close to $1$, the approximation is
$$\frac {A_n}{B_n}\sim \frac{e}{e-1}-\frac{2 e-1}{(e-1) n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ and then the required limit.

Reminder: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4255290

@Gary. Sorry for having missed it.

This can also be solved by measure theory. Define the sequence of functions on $\mathbb{R}$ as follows
\begin{gather*}
    \begin{aligned}
        f_n(x)=\begin{cases}
        \left(1-k/n\right) \ {}^n,\quad & k< x\le k+1,\quad 0\le k\le n\\
        0,\quad & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases},
    \end{aligned}\\
    \begin{aligned}
        f(x)=\begin{cases}
        e^{-k}, \quad & k<x\le k+1,\quad k\ge 0\\
        0,\quad & \text{otherwise}
        \end{cases}
    \end{aligned}.
\end{gather*}
For any $x\in\mathbb{R}$, we have $f_n(x)\le f_{n+1}(x)$ and $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=f(x)$. Therefore, by the Levi Monotone Convergence Theorem, we obtain
\begin{gather*}
    \sum_{k=0}^\infty\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_\mathbb{R} f_n(x)dx=\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)dx=\sum_{k=0}^\infty e^{-k}=\frac{e}{e-1},\\
    \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^1+n^2+\cdots+n^n}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1^n+2^n+\cdots+n^n}{n^n}=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left(1-\frac{k}{n}\right)^n=\frac{e}{e-1}.
\end{gather*}

In definition of $f_n(x)$, is the condition $0\leq k\leq n$ written separately? It stays odd.

@ Bob Dobbs. Sorry, this way of writing can indeed be a bit confusing.
